# Rendering performance

Tags: java, performance

I am using ArcGis Java SDK for creating a map in my JavaFX application. I have a requirement to plot up to 500,000 graphics on graphics layer. When I do 100,000 graphics its performance is really bad. It takes 10-15 seconds to render the Base map and Graphics layer. I cannot use any online map because this application is running on a machine that has not internet connection.

```
    jMap = new JMap();  
    ArcGISLocalTiledLayer tiledLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(“Texas_UL3D_Test.tpk");  
    GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();  

    jMap.getLayers().add(tiledLayer);  
    jMap.getLayers().add(graphicsLayer);  
    jMap.addMouseListener(new MouseClickListener());  

    final HitTestOverlay overlay = new HitTestOverlay(graphicsLayer);  

    overlay.addHitTestListener(new  


    jMap.addMapOverlay(overlay);               
    jMap.addMapOverlay(new MouseMoveOverlay());  

    Map<String,Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();  

    jMap.addMapEventListener(new MapEventListenerAdapter() {      
        @Override  
        public void mapReady(MapEvent event) {  
           SpatialReference mapSR = event.getMap().getSpatialReference();  
           for(Data data : getAllData()){  
              attributes.clear();  
              Point point = GeometryEngine.project(data.getLongitude (),data.getLatitude (), mapSR);  
              attributes.put("number", data.getNum());  
              attributes.put("name", data.getName());  
              Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, getSimpleMarkerSymbol(data.getStatus()),attributes);
              graphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);                                
           }  
        }  
    });                                   

    chartSwingNode.setContent(jMap);
```

Please help me to improve its performance. Tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image: A map with 200k+ graphics]

A map with 200k+ graphics

Comment: You should reduce the number of graphics by aggregating them. Have a look at clustering and map generalisation technique.

Comment: I can not aggregate them because based on status of data each graphic may have a different color.

Comment: Ten seconds is pretty fast to iterate and render such a lengthy list of features.  You need to reduce the size of the feature array.  If you cluster on  common color or color and quadrant you might obtain the required performance.

Comment: @Vince I can not reduce the size, the requirement is to plot up to 500,000 objects. I will try clustering similar color. Thanks

Comment: Nobody can demand you to draw all the 500000 objects at the same time. With 1000 by 1000 pixel output image it would mean two pixels per object on average. You can for sure select far less stuff to render when zoomed out. With spatial index it is not any trouble to draw all features inside a small bounding box when your users zoom in.

Comment: @user30184 On a map that is not zoomed in you could draw 5 million graphics.

Comment: For my mind it does not make sense. I have layers with one million polygons and 500 million lines and I take care to never render more than 10000 features on screen at any scale. I use scale dependent rules whitch suit for each source dataset. It means some work but it is worth it.

Comment: Anybody knows if I use separate graphics layer for each color will it improve performance.